# C++ - initialize static array of char pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, initialization

How can I make the following array of pointers to a private static class member?

```
class Auth {
private:
    static char *attribs[3];
    attribs[0]="uid";
    attribs[1]="cn";
    attribs[2]=NULL;
}
```

I am out of ideas on how and where (what in .h and what in .cpp?) to put these lines...

Comment: Why are you using strdup for this

Comment: @M.M just a leftover of many tries ...

Answer (score 1):

In `auth.h`:

```
class Auth {
private:
    static char *attribs[3];
};
```

In `auth.cpp`:

```
char* Auth::attribs[3] = { "uid", "cn", NULL };
```

Comment: dat easy .. shame on me! Thank you!

Comment: This is not legal. You can not assign string literals to non-const pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to C++11, you should consider `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays and C-style strings

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Auth {
    private:
        static std::vector<std::string> attribs;
};

std::vector<std::string> Auth:: attribs = {"uid", "cn"};
```